# Did a survey of conservative Christians show 85% would disown their child if they turned out to be homo sapiens?

Tags: religion, christianity

[This Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=989544304450541&set=a.255685207836458.59981.100001849415220&type=3), attributed to the [The Atheist Advocate](http://facebook.com/TheAtheistAdvocate), says:

> We polled over 10,000 conservative Christians
>
> "What would you do, if you discovered that your child was a homo sapien?"
>
> 85% said they would disown them and force them to leave their home!

Can anyone confirm the existence of this poll?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There was no poll. This was intended to be satirical, but appears to have missed its mark in many places.

It was [originally posted](https://www.facebook.com/TheAtheistAdvocate/photos/a.126561567389326.11059.122675341111282/984548181590656/?type=3&theater) on a Facebook page for the The Atheist Advocate.

In response to complaints, the [poster writes](https://www.facebook.com/TheAtheistAdvocate/photos/a.126561567389326.11059.122675341111282/984548181590656/?type=3&comment_id=1030649756980498&reply_comment_id=1036858606359613&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D):

> The original meme is a caricature, based on the fact that many conservative Christians think about homosexuals in a negative way. The statistics are exaggerated, much in the same way a caricature of a portrait is an exaggeration of one's facial features.

Comment: Comments are for improving answers, not for sharing political opinions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34115/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-did-a-survey-of-conservative-christians-show).